# Java Firebase Do not send password reset if the string is null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am creating an activity that allows you to send a reset link to the mail in the edittext only when the content of the editext is not a null string. But my control isn't working. This is the complete code:

```
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    private String email;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_resetpsw);

        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        Button btn_rst = findViewById(R.id.btn_resetpasswr);
        EditText emailtxt = findViewById(R.id.txt_emres);


        btn_rst.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                        email = emailtxt.getText().toString();
                         if(email != "") {
                        fAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email inviata!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(resetpsw.this, accesso.class));
                    }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Practically in any case, even when the string is empty (= "") the condition is true and therefore I have this error:

> 2021-06-02 16:26:55.015 28645-28645/com.conta.pophome
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.conta.pophome, PID: 28645
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
> at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotEmpty(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.1.0:5)
> at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.1:1)
> at com.conta.pophome.resetpsw$1.onClick(resetpsw.java:37)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
> at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

I honestly don't know why the condition is true even when the string is an empty string. Could someone help me? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use isEmpty() method.

```
email = emailtxt.getText().toString();
    
       if(email.isEmpty())
       return;
    
    fAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email inviata!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(resetpsw.this, accesso.class));
```